# Wait until SSM is ready on instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, aws-ssm

I want to run an Ansible Playbook right after an EC2 instance is created. But I always get connection issues as the instance is not ready:

> An error occurred (TargetNotConnected) when calling the StartSession operation: i-03d60782f0c67e5a1 is not connected.

I tried using wait_for_connection task but it runs till it fails because it gets to the timeout:

```
  - name: Wait for connection
    wait_for_connection:
      timeout: 300
```

But in parallel the instance is ready and I can connect using AWS CLI:

```
> aws ssm start-session --target i-03d60782f0c67e5a1              

Starting session with SessionId: username-091002498546c0ecc
$
```

How to wait for SSM agent to run the playbook?

A hosts entry:

```
      hosts:
        hostxy:
          ansible_host: i-03d60782f0c67e5a1
```

Ansible ran with:

```
--extra-vars='ansible_connection=community.aws.aws_ssm'
```

Comment: `I tried using wait_for_connection task but it runs forever` <= you mean more than 300 seconds (the configured timeout) without failing or succeeding ?

Comment: It times out. Fixed it in my question.

Comment: The module has several other parameters. Did you try to play with those? (`delay`, `sleep`, `connect_timeout`, .....). Moreover, did you run the playbook in verbose mode (`-vvv`) to get a chance to see what is happening under the hood?

Comment: unrelated: you can put the `ansible_connection` var directly in your inventory, for the given host or for an entire group (even for `all` if you use this for all your targets).

Comment: I couldn't find a solution in Ansible. Now I moved the connection check into the Python script that is run before using boto3: `ssm_client.get_connection_status()`. And the Playbook is launched via SSH tunnel using SSM port forwarding. (This was required as I don't have internet access on the instances and Ansible SSM requires s3 bucket access)